# Getting incorrect response in JsonP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am sending data from `index.php` file to another `exec.php` file using `$.ajax` method and executing the data on that file  now when i am sending back output data using jsonp callback  i am getting incorrect data on index.php. I am also writing same output data into a txt file on `exec.php` and i am getting correct data in txt file.

here's my ajax call from index.php

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'exec.php',
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            data: {code : code},
            success: function(data) 
            {
                alert(data);
                $(loader).addClass('hidden');
                var stdout = $(form).children('.stdout');
                if (data.search("Parse error")>0)
                {
                    var str = data.replace('<b>Parse error</b>:  ','');
                    $(stdout).html(str);
                    $(stdout).removeClass('hidden');    
                }   
                else
                {
                    $(stdout).html(data);
                    $(stdout).removeClass('hidden');
                }   
            },
             error: function (status,req,err) { 
             var errorMessage = err || req.statusText;
                alert(errorMessage);
             }, // When Service call fails             

            responseType: "jsonp"
        });
```

Here's my json callback code from exec.php

```
$result = str_replace('"','\"', $script_output);
$script_output = str_replace('"','\"', $script_output);
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,$script_output);
fclose($file);
//print "processJSON({'result':'$result'})";
header('Content-Type: application/jsonp');
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{'result' : '$result'}" . ')';
```

Now here's the response i am getting in firebug.

Screenshot - http://screencast.com/t/nqdAR7JedMk
I'm getting this error by alert through error of ajax method
Screenshot - http://screencast.com/t/5RRlYiha2C0

Please suggest me what i am getting wrong

Comment: Nothing in the code you're provided will create that response. (And don't show us pictures of error messages and responses, quote them in the question)

Comment: Why do you use JSONP? It should be used only for cross-domain requests and linking to exec.php isn't cross-domain... Is it working right with JSON dataType?

Comment: i am write the output in one text file and after that i have use json callback function. and in text file desired output is written. so i dont think that my code which i have not provided here is generate a response

Comment: Where is the rest of the code, also if you jsonp response function is static you'll have to tell jquery what it is. (jsonpCallback: "callbackName")

Comment: i am using jsonp for cross domain

Comment: @user2372214 — If it is too confidential to post in public, then it is too confidential to give to a complete stranger. Write a reduced test case instead.

Comment: var code= "code=" + code; is this correct syntax for define code before send it to server with $ajax method???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have find my answer. The extra numbers is return with json call back. so i have commented out and my some code and my perfect output is here,

```
$result = str_replace('"','\"', $script_output);
$script_output = str_replace('"','\"', $script_output);
//$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
//echo fwrite($file,$script_output);
//fclose($file);
//print "processJSON({'result':'$result'})";
header('Content-Type: application/jsonp');
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . "{'result' : '$result'}" . ')';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something in your code that prints number (2311 on your screenshot) before the line
`print "processJSON({'result':'$result'})";`.

That number before identifier makes javascript code invalid.

Comment: var code= "code=" + code; is this correct syntax for define code before send it to server with $ajax method???